# Mongo aggregation & distinct

Tags: mongodb, distinct, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say my collection has user names , repository names and unique commit id.

```
{"name" : "a","commit_id": "078d40cc537","repo": "r1"},
{"name" : "b","commit_id": "078d40cc538","repo": "r2"},
{"name" : "c","commit_id": "078d40cc539","repo": "r3"},
{"name" : "a","commit_id": "078d40cc540","repo": "r1"},
{"name" : "c","commit_id": "078d40cc541","repo": "r1"},
{"name" : "c","commit_id": "078d40cc542","repo": "r3"},
{"name" : "d","commit_id": "078d40cc543","repo": "r1"}
```

I would like to generate an output grouped by  repository with # distinct users and total commits.

```
repo:"r1" , distinct_users:"3", total_commits:"4"
repo:"r3" , distinct_users:"1", total_commits:"2"
repo:"r2" , distinct_users:"1", total_commits:"1"
```

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two grouping pipeline stages. But you may be missing that [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) isn't just for adding `1`'s:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "repo": "$repo", "name": "$name" },
        "commits": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.repo",
        "distinct_users": { "$sum": 1 },
        "total_commits": { "$sum": "$commits" }
    }}
])
```

Comment: I had to modify the second `$group` to group by `"_id": "$_id.repo"` to generate desired output.

Comment: @harishvc Have no idea what you are talking about. The above results in your output with the exception of the "repo" under `_id`. But a `$project` to do so is un-necessary extra work. Therefore omitted.

Comment: Using your logic I get the following output `[{u'total_commits': 7, u'_id': None, u'distinct_users': 5}]` . When the second `$group` is modified to `{ "$group": {"_id": "$_id.repo","distinct_users": { "$sum": 1 },"total_commits": { "$sum": "$commits" }}}` the output is grouped by repository with # distinct users and total commits.

Comment: @harishvc You need to learn to move beyond "cut and paste" from other peoples code and realize where the obvious "typo" is. Corrected.